# A bitmap context cause memory leaks

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, bitmap, swift3, core-graphics

Now,i'm studying swift3,and i use instrument to check my code, and i find some leaks, but i don't know why, can anybody help me? 
i don't know how to describe my question in details,this is the code which occur leaks

```
private lazy var cacheContext: CGContext? = {
    let bitmapWidth = Int(self.bounds.size.width)
    let bitmapHeight = Int(self.bounds.size.height)
    let bitmapBytesPerRow = bitmapWidth * 4
    let bitmapBytesCount = bitmapBytesPerRow * bitmapHeight
    let bitmapData = malloc(bitmapBytesCount)//calloc(bitmapBytesCount, MemoryLayout<CChar>.size)

    if bitmapData == nil {
        return nil
    }

    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.noneSkipFirst.rawValue).union(.byteOrder32Little)
    let context = CGContext(data: bitmapData, width: bitmapWidth, height: bitmapHeight, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: bitmapBytesPerRow, space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)

    context?.setLineCap(CGLineCap.round)
    context?.setFillColor(UIColor.white.cgColor)
    context?.fill(self.bounds)

    guard context != nil else {
        free(bitmapData)
        return nil
    }
    return context

}()
```

And this is the picture of instrument check
[instrument](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKVXx.png)

Comment: it seem it looping of compress image.

Comment: How do i change my code, please?

Comment: It's not clear from that screenshot what is leaking. Can you get the list of leaked objects from Instruments? One thing: how do you release the `CGContext` you create?

Comment: @DaveWeston,Hi,Thank you very much for answer me. When i doesn't need the context, i free the bitmapData,and this is my code in github[here](https://github.com/chkkassd/WeBoard), please help me,I'm a novice of swift, thanks very much.

Comment: Sorry, I read some more about `CGContext` and Swift, and it is automatically managed for you. The code you've provided looks fine to me. If you can make the source accessible somewhere I can take a deeper look at the issue.

Comment: Just got your updated comment. I'll check out your code later tonight.

Comment: @DaveWeston,Thank you very much.

Comment: I tried this last night, but wasn't able to reproduce the issue. Do you have a specific set of steps that reliably reproduce the memory leak?

Comment: @DaveWeston,I just press the left up corner button"+",and present the record view controller,and then instrument occur the memory leak.